# Execute HTTP GET with Apache HttpClient v.4

Tags: java, http, groovy, apache-httpclient-4.x

I'm trying to use Apache HtppClient to execute a HTTP GET and read the response. My current effort looks like this

```
    def listAlertsUrl = "http://example.com/whatever"
    HttpGet listAlertsRequest = new HttpGet(listAlertsUrl)
    HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(listAlertsRequest)
    HttpEntity entity = response.entity
    EntityUtils.consume(entity)

    // newReader() is a method that Groovy adds to InputStream
    Reader jsonResponse = entity.content.newReader()

    try {
        // do stuff with the Reader
    } finally {
        jsonResponse.close()
    }
```

However, when I try to use the `Reader` I get the error:

> Caused by: java.io.IOException: Attempted read from closed stream.

I'm struggling to find examples of how to use HttpClient v.4 because my Google searches only return examples for olderr versions which have completely different APIs.

Comment: Have you looked at their jUnit tests: https://github.com/apache/httpclient/tree/trunk/httpclient/src/test/java/org/apache/http/client/methods ?

Comment: why do you consume the entity?

Comment: @BorisPavlović I don't see any relevant examples in those tests, but thanks anyway

Comment: did you consider reading the documentation, may be? (http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/quickstart.html)

Comment: @njzk2 if you have an answer to my question, please post it. Responding with a series of rhetorical questions isn't helping. FWIW, the examples you posted don't show how to read the content of the response.

Comment: it's not rethorical. you ask a question in which you use a method which, you say yourself, you don't know what it does. I suggest you start by learning what it does. Also, you say you haven't found examples. I think apache gives a few examples in their tutorial, which is why I posted the link.

Comment: @njzk2 as I said, none of those examples answers my question. If you know of one that does, please post it as an answer.

Comment: i don't get it. If your issue is simply that your entity.content is closed when you try to access it, simply remove the consume call, which is what closes the stream in the first place, which is the answer given by @JigarJoshi.

Answer (score 1):

As stated in the comments and in another answer, remove the `EntityUtils.consume(entity)` line. Also, instead of using the `newReader` method, I would recommend `withReader` (it automatically handles closing the stream). I'd also recommend specifying the encoding when creating the reader

```
def listAlertsUrl = 'http://example.com/whatever'
HttpGet listAlertsRequest = new HttpGet(listAlertsUrl)
HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(listAlertsRequest)
HttpEntity entity = response.entity
// specify the encoding of HTTP response instead of using default JVM encoding
entity.content.withReader(entity.contentEncoding.value) { jsonResponse ->
    // do stuff with the Reader
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[`consume()`](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-core-ga/httpcore/apidocs/org/apache/http/util/EntityUtils.html#consume%28org.apache.http.HttpEntity%29)

> Ensures that the entity content is fully consumed and the content stream, if exists, **is closed.**

You are trying to read from closed stream

Answer (score 0):

You could do it like this:

```
String getUrl() throws IOException{
    HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpGet listAlertsRequest = new HttpGet("http://www.google.com");
    HttpResponse response =client.execute(listAlertsRequest);

    String resultBody = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());
    EntityUtils.consume(response.getEntity());
    return resultBody;
}
```